# Changing selector in a Jquery Scrollbar Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, jquery-selectors

I can not figure this out for the life of me. My head is exploding...

I'm using this scrollbar plugin on my site, as it is probably the only actual responsive scrollbar that works. However, I am trying to change the arrow handling. - https://github.com/gromo/jquery.scrollbar/blob/master/jquery.scrollbar.js

On line 324 there is some code as follows:

```
scrollx.scroll.find('.scroll-arrow, .scroll-element_track')
    .on('mousedown' + namespace, function (event) {
```

I am trying to change 'scrollx.scroll.find' to 'this.find' or 'this.container.find' which are variables that are stored above within the file.

Can someone take a quick peak and tell me how I can pass that variable. I tried passing it within the 'each' function that it's in, and then using it but it didn't work and the console reads: 'jquery.scrollbar.js:324 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'find' of undefined'.

Thanks for the help. Any insight is also appreciated.

PS. I have mulitple scrolls on one page, thus having to get it's current container.

Comment: find is function to traverse DOM elements. scrollx.scroll. can't a function that having a find method. can u share a fiddle ?

Comment: Sorry no fiddle, this is a platform. All I am asking is how to pass that selector, which is a variable.

Answer (score 0):

just use:

```
$('.scroll-arrow, .scroll-element_track')
    .on('mousedown' + namespace, function(event) {
}
```

or

```
$(parent id).find('.scroll-arrow, .scroll-element_track')
    .on('mousedown' + namespace, function (event) {
}
```

Comment: I have multiple scrolls on one page, I can't take that off.

Comment: I thought that was pretty obvious but I'll state it in my post.

Comment: u don't have to need to write exact as $(parent_id)
Specify id of parent tag like $("#id")

Comment: this still does not get multiple elements